# Detecting when asynchronous ping is done

Tags: php

I use my IIS7 webserver running PHP in combination with ping.exe to ping internet addresses of our customers. To make the pinging run simultaniously, I did the following:

- Put all the IP adresses to be monitored in a database table
- Made a PHP file called batch.php that generates a batch file pinglist.bat which contains a line like "start php -q c:\inetpub\monitor\autotask\pingip.php IPADDRESS" for every IP and then executes the batch file. By using "start" the batch file does not wait for the previous command to finish.
- Scheduled this batch.php file in Task Scheduler to run every minute.
- pingip.php pings the IP address given in the parameter and then inserts the ping result into a mysql database.

However, I want the script to do some more processing steps (like generate averages for that batch) when all IP's are pinged for that batch of that minute.

The problem is that I don't know when all the simultanious pings are finished since the response time and amount of adresses vary.

What would be the best way? To let batch.php start pinglist.php, then use a while loop to query the database if all results for that batch are there every x milliseconds?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: `What would be the best way?` Use something like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).

Comment: Sorry I want to make ik myself. This is a start of a bigger thing :)

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to calculate the average the instant all the pings are done. Is that really necessary? Would it suffice to calculate the average on the fly when the results are actually requested? (I.e., via SELECT AVG or similar.)

Comment: This is only one of the requirements. In case the "batch" goes wrong for whatever reason I would like to know it since it is a monitoring system. To get quick results from mysql I created 2 tables, one with the most recent pings and one for the archive of pings. Lets say that I ping 250 adresses every minute and I want to keep this data for one month, it would create a table with approximately 1,1 million rows. I guess selecting and sorting data in this table would be quite slow, right? Sorry, I am a noob in this who wants to get better in it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an ascending number as your batch identifier. Have batch.php pass two parameters to pingip.php -- the batch and the IP to ping:

```
$batch = time(); // or whatever
foreach ($ips as $ip) {
  echo "start php pingip.php $batch $ip";
}
```

The pingip.php script should write both the batch number and the result of the ping to the db. Make sure there's an index on the batch number field. Then you can find the most recently run batch number with:

```
SELECT MAX(batch) FROM pings
```

You can find if there are any errors in the last batch with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pings WHERE batch = $batch AND <whatever>
```

And you can find the average with:

```
SELECT AVG(ping) FROM pings WHERE batch = $batch
```

As long as you have an index on the batch field, each of these queries will be very fast. I wouldn't bother separating into two tables, that's just unnecessary work.